Use a Riemann sum to approximate the integral $\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{|x|^{2.5}}(e^{-i\pi\omega\cdot x}-1)dx$ in 1d
Consider the function $f:[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{2.5}}.$ For dimension $d=1,$ Consider the integral below:
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{|x|^{2.5}}(e^{-i\pi\omega\cdot x}-1)dx.$$
Could we approximate this integral by a Riemann sum?
In particular,  if we divide the domain $[-1,1]$ into equal-length partitions $-1<\epsilon<2\epsilon<\dots<n\epsilon=1$(with $\epsilon=1/n$), we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{|k\epsilon|^{2.5}}\epsilon e^{-i\pi\omega\cdot k \epsilon}-C\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{|k\epsilon|^{2.5}}\epsilon \to \int_{0}^1\frac{1}{|x|^{2.5}}(e^{-i\pi\omega\cdot x}-1)dx,\quad\text{for some constant $C$.}$$
Could we bound the difference
$$\Big|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{|k\epsilon|^{2.5}}\epsilon e^{-i\pi\omega\cdot k \epsilon}-C\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{|k\epsilon|^{2.5}}\epsilon - \int_{0}^1\frac{1}{|x|^{2.5}}(e^{-i\pi\omega\cdot x}-1)dx \Big|$$
in terms of $\epsilon$ to get the rate of convergence of the Riemann sum?
Thank you very much for any of your helps!

This integral does not look like it converges. Should it maybe be $1/\vert x\vert^{1.5}$?

I think the integral might not converge, but the Riemann sum should also diverge as $n\to\infty$, so probably we could use the Riemann sum to approximate this integral? @SeverinSchraven

Well, you have a singularity, thus, it will depend on which Riemann sum approximation you choose.

I think we can pick arbitrtary fine partitions in such a way that the Riemann sum approximation converges to a finite number (a Taylor approximation around the origin tells us that the singularity is odd, thus we can make the bad term cancel if we pick for example an odd number of equidistant intervals).

Thanks for your reply! I think I get the idea, could I ask what does it mean by saying that the singularity is odd?@SeverinSchraven

A function is odd if $f(-x)=-f(x)$. If you pick the first nonvanishing term in our Taylor approximation is $i\pi\omega x /\vert x\vert^{2.5}$, which is an odd finction (the rest will be of the order $\vert x\vert^{-1/2}$ which is integrable and I am less concerned about that part).
